# How to update object that was set with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using useState inside my function to have some data about person, receiver of some package in this context, so my object has two the object and the update method, What is the proper way to update this state without mutating

```
const [receiverInfo, setReceiverInfo] = useState({
    receiverName: null,
    receiverPhone: null
  })
```

and I want to update it from `onChange`

```
<TextInput 
        value={receiverInfo.receiverName}
        onChange={ (text) => {
          setReceiverInfo({...receiverInfo, receiverInfo.receiverName : text })
          console.log(receiverInfo)
      } 
    }
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        placeholder="Receiver name" />
```

What I did here is causing error.

Comment: In case you are struggling with this, use ```onChangeText``` not onChange, that is what confused me

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
...
setReceiverInfo({...receiverInfo, receiverName : text })
...
```